# Put a random number into iframe src URL

Tags: html, url, iframe, random

I want a random number behind `?i=`

```
<li>
  <strong>&nbsp; &nbsp;Clip</strong>&nbsp;2<br>
  <iframe src="https://mysite.ml/links/clip2.html?i=" height="350" width="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
</li>
```

Comment: Have you tried to resolve this yourself? If so, could you please show us the code? If not, give it a shot and update your question / create a new one.

Comment: Try using javascript to dynamically set the src with the url plus a random number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your `iframe` has an `id` attribute, for example:

```html
<iframe id="myrandomiframe" src="" height="350" width="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Then `onpageload`, use JavaScript to set the `src` attribute with `Math.random()` appended, For example:

```js
document.getElementById("myrandomiframe").setAttribute("src","https://mysite.ml/links/clip2.html?i=" + Math.random());
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do this when the page loads with JavaScript.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src += rando(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<iframe src="example.com/?i="></iframe>
```

If you need to delve deeper into any of this, I used [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to pick a number between 0 and [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).